# Ionic Application Ionic Serve Issues

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, serve

I have troubles on launching the application on ionic serve. How can i do for resolving this problem? Here is a list of complete errors: ./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
[ng] Error: Emit

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
[ng] Error: Emit

Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - Cannot read properties of null (reading 'fileName')

My ionic version is: 6.20.1
My Angular CLI version: 14.1.0
My Node version: 16.15.0
My Package Manager version: npm 8.5.5

Answer (score 0):

Try next steps:

1. remove node_modules folder
2. remove package-lock.json
3. run npm cache clean --force
4. install again all dependencies through npm i